# Facebook can i make a like button that does not open a comment box

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Simple question, that I have not found an answer to.

I just need create a like button (easy) and then make sure that when a person clicks on it, it makes the person like the url, but also to make sure that no comment box appears!

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup! It's totally possible.

Here's a reference from 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/#faqcomments:

> If you are using the XFBML and HTML5 versions of the Like button, people will always have the option to add a comment. If you are using the iframe version of the button, people have the option to comment if you are using the standard layout. If people do add a comment, the story published back to Facebook is given more prominence.

In simple words, when you click on the `Get Code` option, choose the `iframe` version and you'll get the desired result.

Comment: thank you! Cant upvote your answer, not enough repurtation :(

Comment: It's cool! As long as it works :)